# In HTML page .exe app file when download why is Anti-Virus software flagging?

Tags: html, file, download, ssl-certificate, exe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.exe">TARGET</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a html page with a link to a .exe app file. When I click on the link two warning are shown:

```
1) McAfee ===> Be careful. This file is can be dangerous.

2) SmarstScreen ===> Microsoft Defender SmartScreen blocked an unrecognized application from starting.
Publisher: unknown publisher
```

> Chrome Web
>
> Web Server for Chrome, Virtual - Locale
>
> Method = GET / HTTP/1.1 - 200
>
> Locale Address = http://127.0.0.1:5000 ----- and ----- app.exe file address: http://127.0.0.1:5500

My address bar says the site is "not safe" and symbol is " 'i' in circle".

What is solution this problem? SSL certificate?

Something else?

Comment: HTTPS on localhost will not help you here. The problem is the unsigned binary executable you are linking to. Have you looked into signing the application?
I'm not an expert on this but maybe this link helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/use-code-signing-to-simplify-application-control-for-classic-windows-applications

Comment: @line-o What is the signature for the app?

Answer (score 1):

I think most anti virus tools will basically flag all direct unsigned exe files as potentially harmful. This is because a lot of malicious websites will try to trick users into downloading and executing malware this way and this is quite common across the internet unfortunately.

Having an SSL/TLS certificate will stop the unencrypted warning in the URL bar but won't help the above.

I would recommend checking your file with an online scanner such as VirusTotal to see if it is being detected as something malicious and then you can try to fix it. I also recommend that you host your file on a third party file host not on your local machine.

Comment: What is signed exe file?

Comment: It's a kind of digital signature that helps ensure a files integrity and that it is safe to use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

Comment: @thnullptr i could not connection network so sorry i learned it. But even so i have a problem. App is signed. But i see this: "This CA Root certificate is not trusted. Upload this certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store to be trusted." How make this i do not know. Can you help me?